# Conditional Highlighting in Excel

Tags: excel, repeat, highlight

I am looking for a function that helps me see cells highlighted if two columns shared the same value twice but in the same rows. Example, D5 and D10 have the value 3 and again E5 and E10 share the values2. In this case both columns D and E shared Similar values twice in rows 5 and 10.
Can somebody help?

I tried several attempts but failed.

Comment: I just set Duplicate values in the selected range D:D. Have it set on my classlists to check for duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom formula in Conditional Formatting like this on your entire table:

```
=CountIf(A:A,A1)>1
```

This assumes your table starts in column A.  It is important to remove all '$' anchors from this formula so that the references change appropriately.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it highlighted the whole table as I have many repeated values throughout the table. I just would like to see if two columns got the same values twice in the same rows.

Comment: Then perhaps you should put in a little effort and show us an example or two of what you want to match and what you don't want to match.

Comment: Ok. I am creating a test invigilation schedule for my school. In my excel sheet, I have the names of the 32 invigilators starting from A5 through A36. Across the sheet in Row 3, I have the 24 subject tests, exactly from column c till column z. I use room numbers in front of each invigilator. Example John and Sara, invigilators of A7 and A15 are assigned to room 4 on Sunday, column D. In this case D7 and D15 have the value 4. Again on Tuesday they are assigned to room 8. In this case F7 and F15 have the value 8. I need highlighting of these cases so that I got alert of repetition.